# NodeJs shell.openExternal open exe and minimize it

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using this in electron to open an application and it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
require('electron').shell.openExternal('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\myApplication\\myApp.exe"');
```

My issue is that it opens in front of my main application.

Is there a way of making it minimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't minimize the external app, but you can bring the opened app to background by setting `activate` option to `false`.

```
shell.openExternal('pathOrUrl', {activate: false});
```

The only problem is that it will only work on macOS.
On other operating systems, you can focus on your app's window after opening the external link, but it does not always work.

```
window.focus();
// or
window.webContents.focus();
```

[Electron Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shellopenexternalurl-options)